# I just can't get FeedMe to work

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, plugin-feedme

I am trying to use the **FeedMe** plugin to append data to existing entries.

My existing entries have a field that is a unique ID.  It is named `Line Id`.   They also have a blank field named `Program Justification`.

The `.csv` file I am importing has only 2 fields `Line Id` and `Program Justification`.   They should sync with the existing entries.  But, FeedMe keeps throwing an **error**

```
*justAPAF Justification: Unable to match an existing element. Have you set a unique identifier for ["lineId"] and does this have a value? - Element.php:104*
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong.  I use `Line Id` as a unique identifier in multiple database, data parsing and data visualization tools with no issues.

I am sure this is a simple 30 second explanation - but it has stopped me cold in my tracks for 5 days now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe we figured this out over Slack, but the issue here was that you need to actually import your `Line Id` column into your `lineId` field, otherwise Feed Me doesn't know anything about that.

The checkbox to tell Feed Me to use a certain field's value to match existing elements on is one half of the problem - you've already correctly chosen `Line Id`. The issue is you need the other half - what data in your feed is supposed to match up with `Line Id` and `lineId`.

I suppose a less confusing UI would be to have an accompanying dropdown field near those checkboxes to say which bit of data in your feed should you be comparing with.

Comment: Yep - everything is working.  I am closing it now.  Thanks again!